# setting cookie is not working

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm trying to set `Cookie` as follow :-

```
//generate secure token
function  Generate()
{
    $temp = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
    return $temp . md5(md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)));
}

function Set($name, $value, $expire)
{
    $domain = isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? "https://" : "http://";
    $domain .= $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
    setcookie($name, $value, $expire, '/', $domain, isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]), true);
}
```

then am calling it:-

```
$_SESSION['token']=Generate();
Set("token", $_SESSION['token'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
```

my session is being set, but the cookie is not , I can't see what causing the problem!

Comment: Make sure your cookie should be set before any output starts

Comment: am 100% sure am not outputting anything! before it

Comment: If `public function Set()` is a class method, then the call to `Set()` should be something like `$cookie->Set( ... )`

Comment: `var_dump($_COOKIE);` and what do you get?

Comment: `array(1) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "5shvniflvk8du32nqc260mdmp2" }`

Comment: could you paste all code preceding the call to Set from start of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Make your function like this

```
        function Set($name, $value, $expire)
        {
    //        $domain = isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? "https://" : "http://";
//host name should be with out http
            $domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
            setcookie($name,$value,$expire,"/",$domain, isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]), true);
        }
```

And refer the document for [php cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: same issue nothing changed!

Comment: Above code sets cookie in my browser. I can see in firebug.